# Trigger Click from AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, request-headers

I'm using a request header with a key and a value to read from the AngularJS controller. If that header, in this case, is `AppHeaders` is valid and has a custom value, I need to trigger a click from that controller. The code that I have, if something like this:

```
$scope.$applyAsync(function() {
    if (appHeaders != null && appHeaders['header-name'] != null) {
        if (appHeaders['header-name'] == "custom-value") {
            $('.class-name').click();
        }
    }
});
```

What's wrong? I make a deep debug into this and the conditional works fine. I guess that the problem is because the element on the DOM doesn't exist when the click is fired.

Comment: In general I find it better to try to call the click handler function directly rather than fake a click.

Comment: Are you using `.class-name` click function like `$('.class-name').click(function(){ ... })` or `$(document).on('click', '.class-name', function(){ ... })`

Comment: @DuncanThacker I try too with a Click Handler and that doesn't work. @palaѕн I'm using any one of the mentions by you. Only ```$('.class-name').click();``` That's wrong?

Comment: @DuncanThacker though I agree with you that sometimes its better to call the JS function directly, it may not always be possible. Consider following scenarios: 1. `$('.class-name')` is a simple link with no event handler. 2. there are multiple event handlers or there is a possibility that more will get added later. 3. `$('.class-name')` element is being created / added to DOM by a 3rd party code and we are not sure which function is handling the click event (may be anonymous).

Comment: @JonathanBrizio we will need to see more of your code to give any suggestion. But first, while debugging the code what is the count of elements matched by `$('.class-name')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys! The final solution results on apply the $broadcast event on the functions declared and use a counter to validate the last cycle of the calls to trigger the click on the element.

```
// Here we declare an empty array to store each request
var requests = [];

// Our first function
$scope.firstFunction = function() {
    // Execute broadcast event with the name of the function
    $scope.$broadcast('requestEnded',requests.push('firstFunction'));
};

// Our last function
$scope.secondFunction = function() {
    // Execute broadcast event with the name of the function
    $scope.$broadcast('requestEnded', requests.push('secondFunction'));
};

// This listener is executed each time that requestEnded is fired
$scope.$on('requestEnded', function(event, countRequests) {
    // Here we validate that the count of requests is the desire
    if (countRequests == 2) {
        // Trigger Click
        $('.class-selector').click();
    }
});
```

I write a post with the entire research explaining this:
https://jbrizio.github.io/2017/10/20/Trigger-click-when-determinate-requests-finish-using-AngularJS.html